# Sending additional parameters with blueimp fileupload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-file-upload, httpcontext, blueimp

I'm using blueimp file-upload's capability to send additional parameters back to the server that are set inside `add`:

```
var simpleImport = false, replaceImport = false, mergeImport = false;   
$uploadButton.fileupload({
            url: myURL,
            formData: { simple : simpleImport, replace : replaceImport, merge : mergeImport }, 
            add: function (e, data) {
                var valid = true;
                // validation logic
                if (valid) {
                    if (condition №1) simpleImport = true;
                    else if (condition №2) replaceImport = true;
                    else if (condition №3) mergeImport = true;
                    data.submit();
                }
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                if (data.result) {
                    oTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            },
            fail: function (e, data) {
                alert("shit happens");
            }
        });
```

On the server I read them in a such way:

```
var merge = Convert.ToBoolean(Context.HttpContext.Request.Form["merge"]);
var simple = Convert.ToBoolean(Context.HttpContext.Request.Form["simple"]);
var replace = Convert.ToBoolean(Context.HttpContext.Request.Form["replace"]);
```

But despite changing its values inside `add` I still got all of them equal to `false` in my handler. Is there any method to obtain proper values except using hidden inputs or I'm doing something entirely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I finally solve this issue: instead of adding additional parameters in settings object:

```
$uploadButton.fileupload({
      url: myUrl,    
      formData: { additional params },
      ....
});
```

they should be specidied directly before submitting the data in `add` method:

```
add: function (e, data) {
    .....
    data.formData = { additional params };
    data.submit();
},
```

Comment: Trying to find something like this since the last 2 hours. Super Helpful. Cheers mate!